# Context in EmberJS RSVP onerror handler

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, rsvp.js

I am implementing error logging in my EmberJS application much as is described [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/capturing-and-reporting-errors-in-production/2647) and it's working pretty well.  The only part that is throwing me off is how to properly handle error calls from the Ember RSVP `onerror` event.

Errors produced from within the Ember run loop are nicely formatted with `message` and `stack` properties, but errors raised from RSVP give back a standard XHR response and no additional context.  Is it possible to access any information about what Ajax call was being executed when this error occurred?

I am using Ember 1.3.1 and Ember Data 1.0.0+b6.

Comment: What do your ajax calls look like and how to you resolve the success/error hooks?

Comment: @AlexLynham I'm not making direct Ajax calls, Ember Data handles all that.

Comment: My guess is it's something to do with how RSVP resolves the ajax promise and how you can handle the values returned from that.

Comment: Conversation with the Ember Data team here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1727

Comment: Ahh, I'm with you. So the standard XHR Ajax error object isn't giving you enough to debug with? What is your baseline (ideal scenario) for getting a more helpful log? Some kind of stack trace detailing exactly at what point the error happened?

Comment: @AlexLynham ideally, yes, but it sounds like call stack stitching between the Ajax caller and promise finish is a feature the browsers will have to implement.  In the meantime I just create my own error object using the status and response text as my message.  It's not ideal since I lose the first half of the call stack, but I'd rather know an error is occurring with partial context than none at all.

Comment: That sounds familiar. In doing an API call using an Ember app I ended up abandoning getting a more useful stack and just mixing a combination of the Ember promise and API status into an object. Not perfect, but eh.

Comment: This likely should be addressed within ember-data, rather then rejecting with the jqXHR it could craft a more useful Error

Comment: that being said, RSVP is only passing you the reason the ajax operation failed, but the reason originates in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a dirty workaround to get context from RSVP internals. You can overwrite RVSP.Promise._onerror method and include some data. 'this' object has _label property which contains sometime useful info about model.
My solution is still not ideal but it is something.

```
#RSVP _onerror hack
#put this before creating application
oldMethod = Em.RSVP.Promise.prototype._onerror
Em.RSVP.Promise.prototype._onerror = (reason) ->
  reason.label = this._label
  oldMethod(reason)

App = Ember.Application.create(options)
```

And little improved code to hook on standart onerror method

```
 Ember.RSVP.configure('onerror', (error) ->
   #handle situation when user in other tab logout from application.
   if error.status == 401 #not authorized
     window.location = '/login'
   else
     niceError = unless error.stack
       message = {
         label: error.label,
         status: error.status,
         statusText: error.statusText,
         state: error.state(),
         readyState: error.readyState,
         responseText: error.responseText.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '').substr(0,100)
       }
       new Error(Ember.inspect(message))
     else
       error

 #here is method to send notification about error
 MessageApp.errorHandler('RSVP', niceError)
```